# How to search by user_id or user_name in Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

Can someone please tell me how I can retrieve Tweets by a certain `user_id` or `user_name` using Tweepy? So far I only have this:

```
new_tweets = api.search(q=keyword, count=tweetsPerQry, geocode="23.5021579914,40.8558165767,500km" )
```

which return Tweets by a certain geolocation, but I want it to return Tweets by `user_id`.

Comment: Here's their API reference https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user-methods

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev there's no command there that to retrieve tweets by user_id

Comment: @GaMeRGaMeR in the API reference look for `.statuses_lookup()`

Comment: There's a `.user_timeline` method, does it not do what you intend? https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`API.user_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline), which uses [the GET statuses/user_timeline endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline).